# Dynamic template arguments for an Ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, glimmer.js

I've run into a situation with a glimmer component that renders a `LinkTo` component within. The issue is that `LinkTo` treats the case where `@model={{undefined}}` and the case of omitting the `@model` argument as 2 different cases. This is because the default value for it is a [special value of UNDEFINED](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v3.24.0/packages/%40ember/-internals/glimmer/lib/components/link-to.ts#L306). When this happens the component uses JS to make the transition i.e. the href is `#` and so you can't use browser commands like *Open in new tab* to open the resulting link. So I tried using inline `if`s

```
    <LinkTo @route={{@route}}
    {{if @model (concat "@model={{" @model "}}")}}
    {{if @query (concat "@query={{" @query "}}")}}
    >
    {{yield}}
    </LinkTo>
```

however, much as I expected this does not work. I've had to resort to having multiple `if` blocks like so:

```
    {{#if @model}}
      <LinkTo @route={{@route}} @model={{@model}} @query={{@query}} @replace={{@replace}}>
        {{yield}}
      </LinkTo>
    {{else if @models}}
      <LinkTo @route={{@route}} @models={{@models}} @query={{@query}} @replace={{@replace}}>
        {{yield}}
      </LinkTo>
    {{else}}
      <LinkTo @route={{@route}} @query={{@query}} @replace={{@replace}}>
        {{yield}}
      </LinkTo>
    {{/if}}
```

This works, but is rather verbose and requires a lot of duplication. Is there a way to dynamically pass `@model` only when it is specified to the parent component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you should do is always to rely on `@models`.

You could do this:

```
<LinkTo @route={{@route}} @models={{this.models}}>{{yield}}</LinkTo>
```

and in js:

```
get models() {
  if(this.args.model) {
    return [this.args.model];
  }
  if(this.args.models) {
    return this.args.models;
  }
  return [];
}
```

Comment: This definitely helped reduce the verbosity of my component. Thanks! I still wonder if there is a way to specify dynamic arguments to a component though.